# What causes this strange Posterization when changing to B&W?

Tags: photoshop, black-and-white, banding

I have this image that was taken several years ago with a D70.

[image]

It was taken at 1600 ISO which obviously makes it quite noisy. I really want to convert it to black and white, but when I desaturate it in PS it immediately reveals quite terrible banding on the fingers of the guitarist.

[image]

Can someone explain why this is, and what I might do to

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The image has some highlights where there is some blue mixed in, where there is otherwise only information in the red and green channels. It's those highlights that doesn't balance well when you desaturate the image.

You can use the Channel Mixer in Monochrome mode to convert the image, that allows you to balance the channels to avoid the posterising.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Ahh, Very good! I've never messed with the channel mixer, I'll give it whirl. Thanks!

Comment: @CircleB Channel Mixer is an essential tool when doing black and white conversions; not only can you avoid problems like this, but in working with the different blend of colors you can significantly alter the mood of your resulting image.

Comment: I can see that! I should've known...

Comment: It is like using color filters back in the days of B&W film. You can cut the tonal value of some colors while keeping the full value of other colors.